Change the width of a @Html.DropDownList in mvc5 Razor
estoy trabajando en un proyecto con MVC5 Razor y me gustaría cambiar el ancho de un @Html.DropDownList. He intentado varios enfoques, como modificar el estilo, cambiar las clases de Bootstrap e incluso separar el @Html.DropDownList del formulario para ajustarlo mejor, pero nada parece funcionar.
Lo que realmente necesito es que el ancho del @Html.DropDownList se adapte dinámicamente al tamaño del texto que se muestra. En mi caso, el texto dentro del dropdown puede ser bastante largo, a veces con más de 100 caracteres. Debido a esto, es importante que el dropdown se ajuste automáticamente para mostrar el texto completo sin cortar o truncar.
Además, estoy utilizando Twilio para enviar mensajes a través de mi aplicación, y las plantillas de mensaje que utilizo se almacenan en una base de datos en una tabla llamada TwilioTemplates. La idea es que estas plantillas se carguen en el DropDownList para facilitar el proceso de selección al enviar mensajes. Esto debería simplificar el proceso y hacer que el envío de mensajes sea más eficiente.
Agradecería cualquier sugerencia o solución que me permita ajustar el ancho del DropDownList de acuerdo con la longitud del texto, manteniendo la integración con Bootstrap y Twilio.
The code is
@using (Html.BeginForm("EnviarInformacion", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Enviar mensaje</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Sección</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("seccionId", (SelectList)ViewBag.Secciones, "Seleccione una sección", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Profesor Guía</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("profesorId", (SelectList)ViewBag.Profesores, "Seleccione un profesor", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Plantilla WhatsApp</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("TemplateTwilio", (SelectList)ViewBag.Templates, "Seleccione una plantilla", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Primer datos</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="Campo1" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Segundo dato</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="Campo2" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Tercer dato</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="Campo3" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Cuarto dato</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="Campo4" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Cuarto dato</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="Campo5" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Cuarto dato</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="Campo6" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-default" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

Por si funciona, este es el controlador
public ActionResult EnviarInformacion(int seccionId, int profesorId, string TemplateTwilio)
{
    string campo1 = Request.Form["Campo1"];
    string campo2 = Request.Form["Campo2"];
    string campo3 = Request.Form["Campo3"];
    string campo4 = Request.Form["Campo4"];
    string accountSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"];
    string authToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"];
    string fromNumber = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TWILIO_WHATSAPP_FROM"];

    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    string sqlQuery = @"SELECT DISTINCT E.Numero_Encargado 
            FROM Seccion S 
            INNER JOIN estudiantes E 
            ON S.cedula = E.cedula 
            WHERE S.IdSeccion = @seccionId 
            AND S.ProfesorGuia = @profesorId";

    List<string> resultados = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(sqlQuery,
                    new SqlParameter("@seccionId", seccionId),
                    new SqlParameter("@profesorId", profesorId)).ToList();

    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
    // Convertir el resultado a una lista
    foreach (var num in list)
    {
        // Define the recipient's WhatsApp number
        var toNumber = new PhoneNumber($"whatsapp:+506{num}");

        // Define the template SID and variables
        var templateSid = TemplateTwilio;

        // Create the content variables
        var contentVariables = new Dictionary<string, Object>()
            {
                { "1", campo1 },
                { "2", campo2 },
                { "3", campo3 },
                { "4", campo4 }
            };

        // Serialize the content variables to JSON
        var contentVariablesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contentVariables, Formatting.Indented);

        // Print the message content to the console
        Console.WriteLine("Message Content: " + contentVariablesJson);

        // Send the message
        var message = MessageResource.Create(
            from: new PhoneNumber(fromNumber),
            to: toNumber,
            messagingServiceSid: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            contentSid: templateSid,
            contentVariables: contentVariablesJson
        );
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var profesores = db.profesoresses
    .Select(p => new
    {
        Id = p.id_profesor,
        Nombre = p.nombre
    })
    .OrderBy(p => p.Nombre)  // Ordenar por el campo 'nombre' que empieza con el apellido
    .ToList();

    ViewBag.Secciones = new SelectList(db.Secciones, "Id", "Seccion");
    ViewBag.Profesores = new SelectList(profesores, "Id", "Nombre");
    ViewBag.Templates = new SelectList(db.TwilioTemplates, "ID", "Ejemplo");
    return View();
}


Hola, no se que tan buena práctica es lo que deseas realizar, pero ya intentaste agregar un style="width:auto;" a cada uno de tus dropdownlist? Esto en caso que desees que se haga más ancho conforme se extienda el contenido.

This question is similar to: Cómo puedo hacer que un  se reduzca o expanda (ajuste) según lo seleccionado?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
